# knex.raw for expression type doesn't seem to work?

Tags: typescript, knex.js

I use a global list of database connections and get the current connection to use from that list.

If I then try to use knex.raw on this connection I get a typescript error:

```
function getDB(config_name: string, maxConnections: number = 1): Knex {
    if (!!cfg && !!cfg.datastores && !!cfg.datastores[config_name]) {
        if (databases[config_name]) {
            return databases[config_name];
        } else {

            const config = cfg.datastores[config_name];
            const db = knex({
                client: 'pg',
                connection: config,
                pool: {min: 0, max: maxConnections},
            });
            databases[config_name] = db;
            return db;
        }
    } else {
        throw new Error('config not initialized, can\'t load db');
    }
}

//somewhere:
const theDb = getDB('whatever');
theDb
    .from('customer')
    .select('*')
    .whereILike(bondinet_db.raw('CAST(c.customer_number AS text)'), '%1%');
```

The above gives on compiling the following error:

```
  Overload 1 of 18, '(columnName: never, value: Readonly<Raw<never>> | null): QueryBuilder<{}, DeferredKeySelection<{}, string, false, {}, false, {}, never>[]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Raw<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Overload 2 of 18, '(columnName: string, value: Value): QueryBuilder<{}, DeferredKeySelection<{}, string, false, {}, false, {}, never>[]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Raw<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Overload 3 of 18, '(sql: string, bindings?: ValueDict | RawBinding | readonly RawBinding[] | undefined): QueryBuilder<{}, DeferredKeySelection<{}, string, false, {}, false, {}, never>[]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Raw<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

How would I correctly type this? Is `// @ts-ignore` the best way?